# Timeout after 10 minutes while running function app with premium app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

I have 2 function apps which use Premium (EP1) App Service Plan as follows:

[image]

Here is how host.json files look like in these 2 function apps:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "SessionHandlerOptions": {
        "MaxAutoRenewDuration": "00:10:00",
        "MessageWaitTimeout": "00:10:00",
        "MaxConcurrentSessions": 1,
        "AutoComplete": false
      }
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On running these function app, I see a timeout occurring after 10 minutes. My understanding is that in the Premium plan, the run duration defaults to 30 minutes to prevent runaway executions. What am I missing? Should I just add/update the following line to fix this?

"functionTimeout": "00:30:00",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default timeout for premium plan is 30 minutes, but if you have set it to another value in `host.json` -> `functionTimeout` section, then the default value will be ignored.

So you're right to change the value in host.json like you mentioned: `"functionTimeout": "00:30:00"` .

But you should also know the timeout limitation for `http triggered function`, see Note section in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout).